# Infinite autoplay slider React js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[Rows Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoIJH.jpg)

In the above picture, I want the rows to move to the left infinitely.

Below is the component code:

```
 <div id={id} className="row__posters">
          {movies.map((movie) => (
            <img
              key={movie.id}
              onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
              className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__posterLarge"}`}
              src={`${base_url}${
                isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
              }`}
              loading="lazy"
              alt={movie.name}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
```

And here is the css for the component code:

```
.row {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.row__posters {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
}
.row__posters::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.row__poster {
  max-height: 100px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: transform 450ms;
}
.row__poster:hover {
  transform: scale(1.08);
  opacity: 1;
}
.row__posterLarge {
  /* overflow-x: scroll; */
  max-height: 250px;
  /* width: calc(250px * 20); */
  animation: scroll 40% linear =infinite;
}
.row__posterLarge:hover {
  transform: scale(1.09);
  opacity: 1;
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 10));
  }
}
```

I want the large row to have an infinite autoplay slider and the other rows shouldn't be affected.
I tried (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Z780EOzIQs) but nothing happened.
Then I tried react-slick third party (https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/pause-on-hover) and it only broke the rows, it turned them into one column(left-aligned).

Do you have any ideas on how to implement this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use react-slick for that. If you want to make it infinite scroll. You have to change the settings object. Which you pass inside the Slider Component.
Add these two inside the setting -

autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 2000,

to make it infinite scroll you can use -

infinite: true,

You should also mention how many slides to show.

slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 1,

Make sure those properties are these. And you have imported css file inside you component.

import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";